# LibreOffice 5 PPA installation

Tags: release-freya, libreoffice

I am trying to install LibreOffice 5.0 on Freya 64 bit. This is a fresh install and does not have any previous versions of LibreOffice. When I apply the LibreOffice fresh official PPA, I get an error saying that `python3-uno` will not be installed.
This is the exact error message:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreoffice : Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed.`

I have checked that my system does not have any version of `python3-uno` installed. And also the PPA does not provide its own version. Since I am coming from Arch Linux, I am not used to frozen software. I really like the elementary user interface. Any help on installing the latest version LibreOffice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. It was actually very simple and my fault. Coming from arch, i don't know how ubuntu based systems are supposed to work. I just installed the repository version of libreoffice and then added the ppa. The upgrade was flawless and I am running libreoffice 5.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and run the following commands:

**To install LibreOffice 5** :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```